# How to have current date in string format inside the Use State hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I wanted to get today's date in string format (e.g. 2/08/2023 ) inside a `useState` hook variable as an initial value.

Current working code:

```js
const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());

// output: Wed Aug 02 2023 12:52:16 GMT+0800 (Australian Western Standard Time)
```

Here follows what I have tried for outputting (2/08/2023):

```js
// Trial #1
const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date().toLocaleDateString());


// Trial #2
let today = new Date().toLocaleDateString()
const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(today)
```

Unfortunately, both approaches produce the following error:

```
Uncaught RangeError: Invalid time value.
```

Any guesses on how to fix this? Thank you!

Comment: I just test your two trial, but no error: https://playcode.io/1549700

Comment: Do you get the same error when running `new Date().toLocaleDateString()` without attempting to place it inside `useState()`? My guess is you're going to see the same error. I'm guessing `new Date(Date.now()).toLocaleDateString('en-AU')` will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Uncaught RangeError: Invalid time value` error occurs because the `toLocaleDateString()` method returns the date in the format `dd/mm/yyyy`, which is not a valid input for creating a JavaScript Date object directly. To set the initial value of `startDate` as a string in the format `2/08/2023`, you can manually format the date using the `getFullYear()`, `getMonth()`, and `getDate()` methods of the Date object.

Here's how you can achieve that:

```
const currentDate = new Date();
const formattedDate = `${currentDate.getDate()}/${currentDate.getMonth() + 1}/${currentDate.getFullYear()}`;

const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(formattedDate);
```

In this code, we first create a new Date object and then manually construct the desired date string in the format `dd/mm/yyyy`. The `getMonth()` method returns a value from 0 to 11, where 0 represents January, 1 represents February, and so on. Hence, we add 1 to the `getMonth()` value to get the correct month number.

This should set the initial value of `startDate` to today's date in the format `2/08/2023`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use moment.js package:

> npm i moment

And use:

```
moment().format('l'); // 8/2/2023
```

or

```
moment().format('L'); // 08/02/2023
```

Like this:

```
 import "./styles.css";
import moment from 'moment'
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(moment().format('L'));
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{startDate}</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Documentation: https://momentjs.com/